# Create object Date from text in format Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: javascript, datetime

i have in jquery:

```
var start = '2012-11-10 13:10:13';
```

Why this not working:

```
var date = new Date(start);
```

? How can i make it without external plugins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit more correct:

```
var correctStart = '2012-11-10T13:10:13';
var date = new Date(correctStart);
```

Quoting the `Date.parse` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)) doc:

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format.
>   Starting with JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4, a subset of ISO 8601 is
>   supported. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or
>   "2011-10-10T14:48:00 (date and time) can be passed and parsed.

Still, this format is NOT supported by IE8 (as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)). Therefore I suggest at least considering possibility of using external libraries for processing dates - in particular, [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Or  you Can try it as shown below

```
var start = '10/11/2012 13:10:13';    
var date = new Date(start);
```

This is working

Comment: @Oxi try your example with "16/09/2018 10:00:00". When you answer something, worth trying a little (different examples) before posting it...

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/wSvxQ/)**

You have to convert the date string from `Y-m-d H:i:s` to `Y/m/d H:i:s` because javascript does not recognize the date string in that format.

Do this:

```
var my_date = "2012-11-10 13:10:13";
my_date = my_date.replace(/-/g, "/"); //this will replace "-" with "/"
//alert(my_date);
var  javascript_date = new Date(my_date);
```